# Bitwise operations vs. logical operations in C++

Tags: c++, xor

In C++ are the following statements when comparing two integer values for equality the same? If not, why?

```
if(a == b)
  ...do

if(!(a ^ b))
  ...do
```

Comment: @devnull Please do not tag C++ questions with the “C” tag, there is enough confusion already.

Comment: The behavior of ^, !, and == are simple and well-documented. It's trivial and educational to figure this out yourself. This is for school, right?

Answer (score 4):

For integer values, yes. Obviously the `xor` operator will return not-zero if there are any bit differences between A and B, and `!` will invert that. For integer data types, the conditions are equivalent.

For floating point values, because of how you can perform two mathematical operations that "should" give the same result, but they may be represented differently as floats, you should not use either of these to compare floats for equality, you should check whether they are the same to within a small margin of error (an "epsilon").

For pointers...I have no idea why you would want to do this to pointers. But if you really want to do it, then yes, they are the same.

However, there is no reason to do this. With optimizations enabled, they will compile to the same code, without, the first will likely be faster. Why would you use the less-clear `!(a^b)`?

Answer (score 3):

The two comparisons are equivalent: `a^b` is `0` if and only if `a==b`, so `!(a^b)` is `true` if and only if a and b have the same value.

Whether you can call them "the same" depends on what you mean by two different operations being "same." They probably will not be compiled into the same code, and `a==b` is definitely easier to read.